# Reload html page at every tenth minute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update a web-page at every tenth minute 7:40...7:50, etc. How do I do this?
Here is my code:

```
    <body onload="checkTime()">
```

```
    function checkTime(){
        var unixTime = Date.now() / 1000;
        var partTenMinuteTime = unixTime%600;
        var time = unixTime - partTenMinuteTime + 600;
        var difference = (time-unixTime)*10000;
        console.log(difference);
        setInterval(location.reload(),15000)
    }
```

This is all I have, everything else I have tried does not work. I am using location.reload();
My problem is where this function gets called and how to implement it.

Comment: On page load, get current time, calculate millis to next 10 minute interval, `setTimeout()` for that amount of millis. Done.

Comment: use `setInterval(reloadPage,checkTime)`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, but `setTimeOut()` executes once time.

Comment: You only need one time. You're reloading the page anyway.

Comment: @Robby I updated my code but the page just constantly keeps reloading. I tried setTimeout() and setInterval() with the same result. the 15 seconds or any number makes no difference.

Comment: `location.reload()` is a function execution call so reload happens always even before setInterval is executed. Pass function reference `location.reload` to setInterval or setTimeout.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => location.reload(), someAmountOfMillis);`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get nearest 10th min

```
let getRoundedDate = (minutes, d=new Date()) => {

  let ms = 1000 * 60 * minutes; // convert minutes to ms
  let roundedDate = new Date(Math.round(d.getTime() / ms) * ms);

  return roundedDate
}

console.log(getRoundedDate(10))
```

Now you can use `setInterval` or in recursive `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Why reload the page at all? Just use AJAX to query what you need. Here's code you could use to do your AJAX query, or reload the page... the later being a bad practice:

```js
function onTenMin(func){
  const m = 600000;
  let i = setTimeout(()=>{
    func(i); i = setInterval(()=>{
      func(i);
    }, m);
  }, m-Date.now()%m);
}
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
  onTenMin(interval=>{ // if you want you can pass the interval here
    const dt = new Date; 
    console.log(dt.toString());
  });
}); // end load
```

Just pass the function you want to `onTenMin`.

**What's happening here?**

`Date.now()` gives you milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. `600000` milliseconds is 10 minutes. `%` is the remainder operator, so it gives you the milliseconds remaining after division of the `600000`. `600000` minus that remainder gives you how many more milliseconds until the next ten minute time. When that timeout happens it executes the function you pass to `func` then sets an interval which executes every `600000` milliseconds, passing the interval to `func`.

Comment: Speaking about bad practices: you'll be continuously executing the callback in your interval as fast as the JavaScript event loop can process it. And you're not clearing the interval created in `everyTenMin()`, so interval instances will just continue to pile up and execute concurrently.

Comment: The interval created in `everyTenMin()` never gets cleared. After 60 minutes you'll have 6 intervals running.

Comment: You're right about the intervals not stacking. But you still have a zero milli interval tying up the event loop for up to 10 minutes.

Comment: Yeah, if OP wants to change that part of the code, they can. I'm well aware that most Browsers can only do `4` milliseconds, and the `0` means as fast as possible, which is more accurate. The issue is, that if it's not accurate there is more of a chance that `everyTenMin` will be off time eventually.

Comment: Still, I see your point @RobbyCornelissen. Posting to reflect, soon!

Comment: Well, the logic you have wouldn't prevent drift in the interval since it's only executed to create the other interval in `everyTenMin()`. After that, the `everyTenMin()` interval takes over.

Comment: In all honesty, OP's original solution, assuming the math is correct and after removing the bug of calling the function in the `setTimeout()` statement, is probably the most optimal.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how do you like it now?

Comment: Yeah, that's about the best you can do if you need to do this type of execution while staying on the same page. I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the minutes of the current hour and check how many minutes there are until the next 10-minute mark and use `setTimeout`. Your `updatePage` method should also continue to use call itself with `setTimeout`, if you are using AJAX to refresh the page (which makes more sense than reloading).

```
function updatePage(){
    //update page
    setTimeout(updatePage, 10 * 60 * 1000);
}
const now = new Date;
const nextDate = new Date;
nextDate.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
nextDate.setDate(now.getDate());
nextDate.setMonth(now.getMonth());
nextDate.setHours(now.getHours());
nextDate.setMinutes(Math.ceil(now.getMinutes()/10)*10);
setTimeout(updatePage, nextDate - now);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a meta refresh instead don't burden the engine with timers

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

10 minutes = 600 seconds, so... This would automatically refresh your page every 10 minutes exactly.

---

Update

Every Exact 10th Minute Of An Hour

```
var tick = 10*60*1000,
    tock = tick - Date.now() % tick; 
setTimeout( "location.reload()", tock );
```

```js
var tick = 10 * 60 * 1000,
  tock = tick - Date.now() % tick;
setTimeout("location.reload()", tock);

//-----show something on the page----

with(new Date(tock))
document.write("Reloading in: " +
  getMinutes() + " min, " +
  getSeconds() + " sec, " +
  getMilliseconds() + " mil."
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to update at the tenth minute not every ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close with the solution in your question.

A couple of things to note:

- You don't need `setInterval()`, but can use `setTimeout()` instead. After the page is reloaded, you will get a new timeout.
- The callback you pass to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` needs to be a function and not a *function call*. If you include a function call, it will be executed immediately and not wait for the timeout or interval.
- There is no need to create additional intervals to be able to correctly determine the 10 minute mark, as proposed in other answers to this question. You can correctly determine the correct time to call the reload action by doing the calculation you had in your question.
- I'm aware that there are situations where you have too little control over the server code to be able to convert to AJAX, but if possible AJAX or websocket solutions should be preferred over reloading the page.

```js
function reloadAfter(minutes) {
  const millisToWait = minutes * 60 * 1000;
  const millisLeft = millisToWait - (Date.now() % millisToWait);
   
  setTimeout(() => location.reload(), millisLeft);
}

addEventListener('load', () => reloadAfter(10));
```